# Browser is not getting my CSS´s Changes

Tags: css, browser, browser-cache

Well, definitely I´m getting crazy...
I´ve a web proyect in c# (Visual Studio 2015). I changed the images which the website is using. Even, I deleted the old ones. So, I have the new images in the specific folder in the proyect., but when I run the proyect, the web is showing de old images again (wtf). What Am I doing wrong?

As usual, thanks guys...

EDITED:
Only say, thank you so much @Svet, for helping me at the very beggining. Cheers Mate!

Comment: Another information. Before this case, I had the same issue with another pictures (and I didn´t have the issue with others). I solved this problem after recompile several times (clever, isn´t? :P)

Comment: It almost the changes I did in CSS files. I can get refresh the proyect with them... After several refresh, and the last one even so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for saying the obvious but did you try to clear cache on your browser? Cached stuff got me more than once :)

Comment: Well... After your comment... it seems obviously... but, I didn´t think it... It works!! Finally... Thanks Svet...